# How to do a good entity design with recursive child relationships

Tags: database, entity, categories, hierarchy

We need to build a category hierarchy, like

```
Clothing
    Men
        Suits
               Classic
               Modern
               Business
               Party
        Trousers
        Ties
        Beachwear
    Women   
        Dresses
               Gala
               Evening
               Simple
        Skirts
               Long
               Mid-size
               Short
               Mini
        Blouses
        Beachwear
```

I designed the Category entity to have a `belongsTo`parent relationship only ( I think I will need a children property too?). So far, a product would be attached to one category only.

Now the client is saying he thinks it should be a many-to-many relationship, and he thinks we should attach a product to all the categories in the chain (like ProductA should be attached to categories "Mid-size"-"Skirts"-"Women"-"Clothing" each). To me this sounds like overkill and a lot of redundancy. I should have all the other relationships through the parent chain available. 
However, I ask myself if this is realistic, as it actually are relationships which need to be traversed and thus result in additional queries.

What would be a good design for clothing categories? That it be a hierarchy seems to be required by the client (there are also tags).

Answer (score 0):

> (like ProductA should be attached to categories
>   "Mid-size"-"Skirts"-"Women"-"Clothing" each).

It is a standard requirement in e-commerce applications for one product to belong to several categories. It makes perfect sense to any manager.

You should implement tree-traversal using optimal tree functions, not parent-child relationships of Eloquent. Check, for example, this [laravel package](https://github.com/AdrianSkierniewski/eloquent-tree).